# Inability To Solve a System of Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have the following system of equations:
$$\begin{pmatrix}a\cos(x)+b\sin(x)\\
a\sin(x)-b\cos(x)\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
-a\\
-b
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where I am trying to solve for $a$ and $b$.
When I feed this WolframAlpha, I get 2 possible solutions: $$1.\:(a,b)=(0,0)$$ $$2.\:(a,b)=(\cot(x)-\csc(x),1)$$
I don't understand how to find the second answer. Every single thing I have done so far has resulted in me arriving at $1=1$. Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S.
I arrived at this problem initially while trying to find the eigenvectors of the following matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
-1&0&0\\
0&\cos(x)&\sin(x)\\
0&\sin(x)&-\cos(x)
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your linear system as

\begin{cases}
(1+\cos x)a+(\sin x) b =0 \\ (\sin x) a + (1-\cos x)b=0
\end{cases}
The determinant $\:\begin{vmatrix}1+\cos x & \sin x \\ \sin x & 1-\cos x \end{vmatrix}\:$ is $0$ (which we knew, since it corresponds to the eigenvalue $-1$), so that these two equations are not linearly independent.

Therefore you only have to solve one of them, e.g., if $\sin x\ne 0$,
$$(\sin x) a + (1-\cos x)b=0\iff a= \frac {\cos x -1}{\sin x}b=(\cot x-\csc x)b$$
and for the generator of the eigenspace, you can choose $b=1$, whence $a=\cot x-\csc x$.

If $\sin x =0$, you obtain instantly from the linear system $\;a=b=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply first equation by $\sin(x)$ and second equation by $\cos(x)$ and subtract, you get:

$$b(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x))=b\cos(x)-a\sin(x)$$

$$\rightarrow b(1-\cos(x))=-a\sin(x)\rightarrow a=b\frac{\cos(x)-1}{\sin(x)}$$

$$\rightarrow a=b(\cot(x)-\csc(x))\rightarrow b=1\rightarrow a=\cot(x)-\csc(x)$$